# Circular reference in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a database where I have a customer table, a vendor table and an address table. I thought I'd put a customer id and vendor id in each row of the address table, but allow them to be null.

A vendor will likely have one address at a time, but just in case, I'll create it to allow multiple addresses.

A customer will often have 2 addresses, but might have many.

The customer table will have the fields "default_shipping_id" and "default_billing_id"

I can do this without the FOREIGN KEY constraint, but if I try to create these tables with the constraints, I get errors because of the circular reference. Should I make the constraint one-way or can/should I add the constraints after the tables have all been created?

Comment: make the `default_shipping` and `default_billing` a bool on the address table? you may also want to consider consolidating the `customer` and `vendor` tables into one `user` table, and have a type field that is `customer` and `vendor` this way you don't have to join two tables to the address

Comment: There are no circular references here unless you're making the Foreign Key relationships go both ways. If you *do* require this then you should probably switch to Postgres since MySQL transactions do not work correctly in that they do not defer foreign keys checks to accomodate inserts like this.

Comment: @cmorrissey using a BOOL to flag the "default" address may cause inconsistencies, because it allows multiple addresses to be the default address. bad idea.

Comment: I think I might have been better off asking "Should all foreign table references use foreign key constraints?"

Answer (score 1):

Try to be neat and flexible with designing databases. 5 tables for your solutions -

```
1) `address` table
`id`
`address`

2) `customers` table
`id`
`name`
`email`

3) `customer_address_mapping` table
`id`
`customer_id` (FK to `customers` table)
`address_id` (FK to `address` table)
`is_billing` (Boolean field)
`is_shipping` (Boolean field)

4) `vendors` table
`id`
`name`
`email`

5) `vendor_address_mapping` table
`id`
`vendor_id` (FK to `vendors` table)
`address_id` (FK to `address` table)
```

**Explanation:**

`address` table will be a `dump` of all the `addresses` of all `customers` and `vendors`. Both mapping tables will provide you flexibility to add as many addresses you want. `is_billing` and `is_shipping` boolean fields will let you know the type of address of the customer.

Comment: I'd go for the simple `n:m` relation as well. But I'm not upvoting this answer, because it doesn't actually answer the question ;-) The OP asked for an explanation about the FOREIGN KEY relationship, which this answer doesn't address at all.

Comment: Also, i'd opt for a field like `address_type ENUM('shipping', 'billing')` instead of two `BOOL` as you suggest. Two `BOOL`s can both be `false`, allowing potentially unusable/unused addresses.

Comment: A customer might have their item and their bill send to the same address, so the ENUM would not work in that instance unless I allowed a second entry in the mapping table.  My tables are actually more complex than I described, but the concept should be the same anyway. Is there anything wrong with referencing what would be a FK, but not implementing the constraint?